# Rename multiple fields in a MATLAB struct

Tags: matlab, struct, rename, field, batch-rename

I need to rename a bunch of fields in a structure by basically changing the prefix on it.

e.g.

```
MyStruct.your_firstfield
MyStruct.your_secondfield
MyStruct.your_thirdfield
MyStruct.your_forthfield
%etc....
```

to

```
MyStruct.my_firstfield
MyStruct.my_secondfield
MyStruct.my_thirdfield
MyStruct.my_forthfield
%etc...
```

without typing each one out...since there are many and may grow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by [dynamically generating field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) for the output struct.

```m
% Example input
MyStruct = struct('your_firstfield', 1, 'your_secondfield', 2, 'your_thirdfield', 3 );

% Get a cell array of MyStruct's field names
fields = fieldnames(MyStruct);

% Create an empty struct
temp = struct;

% Loop through and assign each field of new struct after doing string 
% replacement. You may need more complicated (regexp) string replacement
% if field names are not simple prefixes
for ii = 1 : length(fields) 
  temp.(strrep(fields{ii}, 'your', 'my')) = MyStruct.(fields{ii}); 
end

% Replace original struct
MyStruct = temp;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm!